# AJAX request loop in a context

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to start several AJAX requests which are tied in a context.

```
function ajaxCall(id){
   $.ajax(  url: "/data/" + id + "/",...)
}

for (var i = 0; i < widget.length; i++)
    window.setInterval(ajaxCall(widget[i]), 50)
```

However this code does not do what I want. I tried using bind(widget[i]), but am a bit lost. How to solve the issue?

Also, are there best practice for wrapping and scheduling ajax calls? I have the O'Reilly book on the topic but it is not very thorough when it comes to these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
window.setInterval(ajaxCall.bind(null, widget[i]), 50)
```